# How to filter out specific web element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I have some code that returns an HTML collection:

```
var list = jsExecutor.ExecuteScript("return document.getElementsByTagName(tagname);");
```

I am using C# and Selenium so I have to inject the JavaScript like you see above. My question is how do I filter out a specific element from this list using JavaScript? I know about the filter command but I don't have enough knowledge to be able to adapt it to this specific problem. I am trying to compare the value of each element to a parameter. I can do this just fine by creating a C# list and iterating through it but I want to be able to use mostly JavaScript.

Comment: What do you want to filter? Specific classes? Specific attributes? What?

Comment: I want to filter each element(tag) in the HTML collection.

Comment: There needs to be something you want to filter out though, where the tag contains what?

Comment: For example `elements.filter(e => e.classList.contains('my-class'))` will filter out elements that don't contain the class `my-class`

Comment: Gotcha. I am trying to filter on the text inside of some textarea tags. If you use .value you can get the text associated with the text area.

Comment: Okay, what should the textarea contain or not contain, what specific text?

Comment: The textarea just contains some names but it doesn't really matter. I just need to be able to compare the text inside every single element until I find the element who's value is the same as the text I pass into the function. The text itself is a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), we can filter the results by using [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to see if a textarea `i.value.includes()` includes a particular string.

```js
function getNames(name, tag) {
  // Get a list of textarea tags and convert them to an array
  const textareas = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName(tag))
  // Filter out textarea's that don't contain the name passed to the function
  return textareas.filter(i => i.value.includes(name))
}

console.log(getNames('Joe', 'textarea'))
console.log(getNames('Steve', 'textarea'))
```

```html
<textarea>Billy</textarea>
<textarea>Bob</textarea>
<textarea>Joe</textarea>
<textarea>Steve</textarea>
<textarea>Joe</textarea>
```

If a case-insensitive search is needed, we can use `toLowerCase()` on both values:

```
i.value.toLowercase().includes(name.toLowerCase())
```